# How login with okta oauth in new heroku app

Tags: javascript, heroku, okta-api

I am using okta oauth in my express-node js app. When I deploy and run the new app in heroku and go through the login page I am getting 404 status code. For some reason, I’m not able to authenticate the legitime of my third part okta app. However, locally, it seems every things are working as expected.

There is anyone of you can help and support it? Thx