# Vue.js, Express Server, Okta, deploy to Heroku, 404 on implicit/callback

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, vue.js, okta

I have an Vue app built with vue-cli and authorized through Okta.  Pushed up to Heroku as a production setup, but I'm kinda wondering if Okta doesn't do production on the freemium level?

Am I missing something in the docs about this...

#### The setup:

Got a `src` dir with the usual things `router/index.js` has Okta library attached:

```
Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: 'dev_url',
  client_id: 'some_string',
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  scope: 'openid profile email'
})
```

and this is in the routes array:

```
{
  path: '/implicit/callback',
  component: Auth.handleCallback()
},
```

Got a `server.js` in `src/` and got some jwt verification and build folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../dist")))
...
const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
    clientId: '<some_id>',
    issuer: '<some_url>'
})
...
app.get('/', authRequired(), (req, res, next) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'))
 })
```

These all seem good, and everything works like a charm on localhost.  Working with webpack-dev-server, but with a push up to heroku I get a 404 on the `implicit/callback` route...

Here are the scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "server": "node ./src/server",
    "start": "node ./src/server",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install && npm run build"
},
```

When build goes through and all the happy times should commence I click on login and this call gets sent out through the browser, which seems a bit weird:

`https://<base_url>.herokuapp.com/implicit/callback#id_token=<huge_hashed_string>&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=openid+email+profile&state=<huge_hashed_string>`

And we crash out on the 404 and no auth occurs.

If you clone it and `npm install` you can run `npm run dev` and `npm start`.

#### Things I've tried:

It's been a lot of route manipulation, not sure what else to mess around with, mostly because it works locally honestly I think I'm either missing something in setting up the Okta app or something in the docs that won't let me run things this way.

I've added the production url to **Login redirect URIs** in dashboard setup. and accepted base urls.  Anyone have any input on this one?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648047/how-login-with-okta-oauth-in-new-heroku-app) is basically the same question I think with a bit less context, asked about 2 months ago, so either this is a very difficult solution or I am missing something very simple.

Comment: So I'm reading about [SAML layers](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SAML/) which it seems like Okta may need to function in production.  Anyone have any context for me here...  is this the right path to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not too bad.  The answer I found is that you have to go back to token storage and use the OktaClient instead of their implicit callback setup.  Solved the problem by following [This tutorial.](https://dzone.com/articles/the-lazy-developers-guide-to-authentication-with-v-1)