# how to solve port issue between heroku and okta?

Tags: node.js, heroku, port, okta

I have a nodejs app that uses okta services for authentication.

The app I tested locally on my pc and it works ok, it starts listening on port 3000:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`))
```

So far so good.
Next step I deployed the app on heroku, but - unfortunately - it doesnt work...
I have inspected the log file and I found the culprit: it seems heroku ignores the port that I set in my .env file to 3000, and it uses a (random?) value for the port, 16709 for example:

> 2020-04-17T09:51:40.261031+00:00 app[web.1]: App listening on port
>   16709

That explains why the authentication fails.
As I see in okta settings, it definitely expects port 3000:

```
Login redirect URIs : http://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback
```

So I'm stuck... I searched stackoverflow and I found this: [How login with okta oauth in new heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50648047/11261826) , but unfortunately theres no answer :(

Please, anyone knows how to mitigate/solve this port issue between heroku and okta?

---

**Update**:
I tried the suggestions from the answer and comments below, but it still doesnt work...
What I get from okta auth is:

> "400 - bad request. You request resulted in an error. Identityy
>   provider: Unknown. Error code: invalid_request."

And here are some logs from okta:

> Outcome
>
> ```
> Reason mismatched_redirect_uri
> Result FAILURE
> ```
>
> Severity WARN System
>
> ```
> DebugContext
>     DebugData
>         AuthCode <removed by me>
>         AuthorizationServer <removed by me>
>         AuthorizationServerName default
>         ClientAuthType client_secret_basic
>         GrantType authorization_code
>         GrantedScopes
>         RedirectUri https://my_app.herokuapp.com//authorization-code/callback
>         RequestId <removed by me>
>         RequestUri /oauth2/default/v1/token
>         RequestedScopes
>         ThreatSuspected false
>         Url /oauth2/default/v1/token?
> LegacyEventType app.oauth2.as.token.grant_failure
> ```

Comment: I have updated my question with the error I got, some logs from heroku and login auth code snippet.

Comment: Maybe you can post the error(s) from okta logs? Those are the most helpful in your case. Heroku log doesnt help much here, as the issue rather seems to be on auth side, i.e. from okta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by inspecting your okta logs, it seems you have an extra "/" in your redirect URL.
This is definitely the main cause of the failure "**mismatched_redirect_uri**".

Please change this (note: double-slash before `authorization-code`):

```
RedirectUri = https://my_app.herokuapp.com//authorization-code/callback
```

with this (note: single-slash before `authorization-code`):

```
RedirectUri = https://my_app.herokuapp.com/authorization-code/callback
```

After the above correction, just try to redo all the tests (login, auth, etc).
I'm 99% sure this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

app Heroku sets a random port internally, but exposes your app to the public on the standard https port (443). So, if you have an app on heroku called: nodejs-okta, the publicly accessible url would be:

https://nodejs-okta.herokuapp.com

You'd need to whitelist this url in your okta app settings so that the redirect works properly:

https://nodejs-okta.herokuapp.com/authorization-code/callback

Note: I work on Okta's developer advocacy team

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I cant find where exactly is the menu to set the URL in the whitelist in the developer console...?

Comment: From the Okta developer console, choose `Applications` from the menu. Click your OIDC application and choose the `General` tab. Click `Edit` and then add a URI to the `Login redirect URIs` section on the page. HTH!

Comment: Oh, already tried that, but it doesnt work. By "whitelist" I thought you were referring to a menu/feature designed for URL whitelisting from within dev-console... Any other idea or what else should I further investigate?